# SQL finding difference between subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table of Salaries and i have to find the difference of averages of rows with zeroes and without,so here is the my query

```
SELECT ((SELECT REPLACE(Salary, '0', '') FROM TEST) - (SELECT ROUND(SUM(Salary)/COUNT(*)) FROM Test)) FROM Test
```

Unfortunately my query is not working.
Example 5 salaries: `5049,7000,2000,3900`
I have to find the average of `5049,7000,2000,3900` and `549,7,2,39`

Comment: How is that a useful calculation?

Comment: @GurV just want to improve my skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.without, a.with, a.with - a.without
FROM(
  SELECT AVG(CAST(REPLACE(Salary, '0', '') AS INT)) AS 'without', AVG(salary) 
  as 'with'
  FROM test) a
```